# selecting different image tag in div CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two images in a `div` that I want to apply different positioning to. In between the two is a form. I have targeted the first image by using `.bookingForm img` but am not sure how to target the second image.
I have tried `.bookingForm img:nth-child(even)` but it didn't seem to work and I'm not sure if I should be using this.

Also, It seems unnecessary to be adding selectors just to do one thing but I am not sure if there is any other way.I don't think putting two different classes on the images seems right as well.

Here is my CSS

```
.bookingForm img {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 90px 0 0 170px;
}

.bookingForm img:nth-child(even) {

}
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: Please add your html also please. so we know how you could identify the elements

Comment: the images are missing but here it is http://jsfiddle.net/vEXwu/

Comment: It might be worth noting that your first selector `.bookingForm img` will target both images, not just the first.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to be explicit in your code. Unless there is a specific reason you want to avoid giving the second image a selector of its own other than "it seems unnecessary", you should make your code cleaner and easier to read by using that selector. This avoids problems down the road if you decide to add more elements between the images, which can obviously mess up your css hack of using nth-child to target the element. Avoiding an extra selector provides  insignificant performance boost and only makes your code a whole lot harder to read to a future you, and to other coders.

Comment: Ok so then it would be better to give them classes and select them using that than using the nth-child option?

Comment: @ev9604 Yep, that's precisely what I am suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 classes for the images [which you don't want to] then you can use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp):

```
.bookingForm img:nth-child(2) {
    margin:5.5em 0 0 10.5px;
}
```

Provided both the image are in the same div **bookingForm**

Comment: would they need classes though if you use nth-child?

Comment: nope. You can directly use them on elements. No need to specifically add classed to img tags. But if you are talking abt bookingForm class then that is used here just for inheritance of the css elements